# How do I tokenize to separate apostrophes?

Tags: python, tokenize, python-3.8

I have a function made to tokenize the words given; however, the problem ensures in the fact that it does separate 'isn't' and 'o'brian' and similar words. This is the code:

```
from typing import List
import re

def tokenize(text: str) -> List[str]:
    return re.sub(r'(\W+)', r' \1 ', text.lower()).split()
```

When I put in something like

```
"He said 'Isn't O'Brian the best?'"
```

it'll come as

```
['he', 'said', "'", "isn't", "o'brian", 'the', 'best', '?', "'"],
```

not

```
['he', 'said', "'", 'isn', "'", 't', 'o', "'", 'brian', 'the', 'best', "?'"]
```

I'm really lost because I've tried to do more than re.sub to separate the words and tried to split them, but it seemingly is not working.

Comment: You can try `re.findall(r"\w+|'|\S+", text)`

Answer (score 1):

You need a better definition of "word", for example:

```
word_re = r"\b[A-Za-z]+(?:'[A-Za-z]+)?\b"
```

that is, a word boundary, then some letters, then optionally an apostrophe, followed by letters. Once you've got it, use `findall` to extract words:

```
words = [w.lower() for w in re.findall(word_re, text)]
```

Comment: Words like "shouldn't've" can have multiple apostrophes - so I suggest replacing the `?` at the end with a `*`.

Comment: @kaya3: sure, it's just an example. Depending on the OP's needs, a definition of "word" might also include `N/A` or `S.T.A.R.S` or `C3PO`

Answer (score -1):

if the apostrophes arent important to the meaning of the word, ie "obrien" and "o'brien" are the same for your purposes you could do some basic text pre-processing to remove all the apostrophes using `text.replace("'","")` see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

if they do matter, you could replace them with Unicode (the unicode for ' is U+0027) and translate them out of Unicode after you've tokenized them, or just `text.replace("'","U+0027")` before you tokenize, and `text.replace("U+0027","'")` after

hope that helps, goodluck!